# jQuery promises not working with method html undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I have the following markup and script:

```
<div id="output" hidden>
    <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var promises = [
        $.getJSON("./MyContacts.js"),
        $("#output").fadeIn("slow"),
            new $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
                setTimeout(dfd.resolve, 5000);
                return dfd.promise;
        })
    ];

    $.when(promises).then(
        function (xhr, faded, timer) {
            faded.html(xhr[0].length + " Contact(s) Found");
        },
        function (xhr, status) {
            $('#output').html("Error retrieving contacts.")
        }
    );
</script>
```

When running the code I get an error message:

> UncaughtTypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined

What is causing this error?

Comment: $ouput <-- what is that? do you mean $('#output').html;

Comment: @jamesemanon - yes, that is what I meant, typed too fast there. :-)

Comment: try this 
var html="Error retrieving contacts."; output.append(html);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) doesn't expect an `Array` of Deferreds, but rather to have each as their own argument.

As the `Array` is not a `Deferred` itself, it's being treated as a *truthy*, auto-resolve. And, `faded` is `undefined` rather than the `$("#output")` you selected since `xhr` actually holds everything.

```
console.log(xhr);
// Array( [jqXHR], [jQuery], [Promise] )
```

You'll want to use `.apply()` to pass `promises` to it:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(/* ... */);
```

Or, for future reference (ES6), use a spread:

```
$.when(...promises).then(/* ... */);
```

---

Also, note that `.fadeIn()` doesn't return a `Deferred` or promise. So, this will be treated an an auto-resolve rather than waiting for the animation.

But, as Bergi mentioned in the comments, you can use the [`.promise()` method](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to create a `Promise` for the `fx` animation queue.

```
$('#output').fadeIn('slow').promise()
```

Comment: +1 - Ahh, that makes total sense now. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Instead of manually constructing the Deferred, you could have used the [`promise` method](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) which returns a Promise for the animation queue.

Comment: @Bergi Nice. Hadn't run across that one before. Thanks.